# DAX Lookupvalue with TOPN and filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to lookup a value from another table with a filter, and a TOPN.

I have two tables like this:

Table1

```
ID   Latest
X-1
X-2
```

Table2 (Key is concatenation of ID and Start)

```
ID  Start    Key    Status
X-1   1     X-1 - 1   Done
X-1   2     X-1 - 2   Done
X-1   3     X-1 - 3   Open
X-1   4     X-1 - 4   Open
X-2   1     X-2 - 1   Done
X-2   2     X-2 - 2   Open
X-2   3     X-2 - 3   Open
X-2   4     X-2 - 4   Open
```

What I'd like to do is, for the empty values in `Table1[Latest]` to find the value in `Table2[Key]` based off the highest number in `Table2[Start]` and only those in `Table2[Status]` with `"Open"` respectively for each `ID` in `Table1`.

So that Table1 ends as:

```
ID   Latest
X-1   X-1 - 2
X-2   X-2 - 1
```

I thought something along the lines of

```
Latest = LOOKUPVALUE(ggTwo[Key], ggTwo[ID], TOPN(1, ggTwo, CALCULATE(ALL(ggTwo[ID]), FILTER(ggTwo, ggTwo[ID] = ggOne))))
```

But this is refering to multiple columns. I am not sure how to tackle this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `MAXX` instead of `TOPN`. For example,

```
Latest = MAXX(
              FILTER(Table2,
                    Table2[Status] = "Done" &&
                    Table2[ID] = EARLIER(Table1[ID])),
              Table2[Key])
```

If you have a relationship based on the `ID` columns, then you don't need the second condition:

```
Latest = MAXX(FILTER(RELATEDTABLE(Table2), Table2[Status] = "Done"), Table2[Key])
```

Comment: Works! Life saver :)

Comment: This worked for my use case too. An Employee is in a team and this team can change during the year which results in a new duplicate entry in the Employee table. The `Valid From` field is used to work out when this change came into effect. So I needed to filter the employee table by name and the valid from in order to find the employee's current team

`Current Team = 
    MAXX(
        FILTER(
            Employee,
            Employee[Name] = Hours[Name] && Employee[Valid From] <= Hours[Date]
        ),
        Employee[Team]
    )`

Answer (score 0):

To get the top start where the status is open, I created a calculated column on table two.

```
LastOpenStart = 
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( ggTwo[Start] ),
    ggTwo[Status] = "open",
    FILTER ( ggTwo, ggTwo[ID] = EARLIER ( ggTwo[ID] ) )

//Query
EVALUATE
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    NATURALINNERJOIN (
        FILTER ( ggTwo, ggTwo[LastOpenStart] = ggTwo[Start] ),
        FILTER ( ggOne, ggOne[Latest] = BLANK () )
    ),
    "ID",ggTwo[ID],
   "Key",ggTwo[Key]
)
```